# How to check if a value is in a list?

Tags: bash, list

I've got a script with a variable taken from command line parameters. I want to check if its value is one of `dev`, `beta` or `prod`. I've got a following code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ENV_NAME=$1

echo "env name = $ENV_NAME"
ENVIRONMENTS=('dev','beta','prod')
if [[ $ENVIRONMENTS =~ $ENV_NAME ]]; then
    echo 'correct'
    exit
else
    echo 'incorrect'
    exit
fi
```

When I run my script, it doesn't matter which parameters I pass: `./script.sh beta` or `./script.sh` or `./script.sh whatever`, I always get `correct` echoed. What is wrong in my script?

Comment: It is working well on my machine (`GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`)

Comment: Could you add some details about your environment / bash version / OS?

Comment: It is working in my environment, too (4.2.25(1)-release).

Comment: It may not work if `$1` gets some special characters on it.

Comment: Try `[[ $ENVIRONMENTS =~ "dev" ]];echo $1` on the colsole. It should return 0 (true) and or 1 (false) if you use another string than "dev".

Comment: because `$ENVIRONMENTS` is interpreted as first element of the array (try `echo $ENVIRONMENTS`) you should use syntax `${ENVIRONMENTS[@]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in ${ENVIRONMENTS[@]}; do
  if [[ $i = $ENV_NAME ]]; then
    echo "correct"
    exit
  fi
done

echo 'incorrect'
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

#### For using bash re:

```
ENV_NAME=dev
ENVIRONMENTS="dev|beta|prod"
[[ $ENV_NAME =~ ^($ENVIRONMENTS)$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Everyone's given a good suggestion already however there's another way. It's more efficient than using regex and probably more efficient than using a loop especially when having more values. The only thing is that this requires Bash 4.0 or newer.

```
declare -A ENVIRONMENTS=([dev]=. [beta]=. [prod]=.)
if [[ -n ${ENVIRONMENTS["$ENV_NAME"]} ]]; then
...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Put it in a function

I like to hide ugly implementation details, especially when it comes to bash.

```
function catPipe()      # concatenate all arguments with a pipe character
{
  local IFS='|'
  echo "$*"
}

function matchList()
{
  local needle="$1"
  shift
  local stack=$(catPipe "$@")
  [[ "$needle" =~ ^($stack)$ ]]
}
```

If you don't like having a subshell, use this:

```
function matchList()
{
  local needle="$1"
  shift
  IFS='|' eval 'local stack="$*"'
  [[ "$needle" =~ ^($stack)$ ]]
}
```

Inspired by konsolebox' solution, I use the ^($var)$ syntax to avoid partial matches. First it looked like this:

```
function matchList()
{
  local needle="$1"
  shift
  local stack="$@"
  [[ ${stack[@]} =~ "$needle" ]]  # would allow partial machtes like 'eta'
}
```

The function can be called with either a string, an array, or single items:

```
variants='dev beta prod'
varArray=(dev beta prod)

matchList prop $variants && echo 'prop: match!'
matchList beta $variants && echo 'beta: match!'
matchList beta ${varArray[@]} && echo 'beta: match!'
matchList eta alpha beta gamma && echo 'eta: match!'
# Output:
beta: match!
beta: match!
```

Or for the original example:

```
matchList $ENV_NAME ${ENVIRONMENTS[@]} && echo 'correct'
```

### case (partial solution)

Side note: I tried to come up with a solution using case, as it would naturally fit the requirements.
It works, but I couldn't figure out if/how I can use ENVIRONMENTS in the statment.

```
ENV_NAME='beta'
ENVIRONMENTS='dev|beta|prod'
case $ENV_NAME in (dev|beta|prod) echo 'correct' ;; (*) echo 'incorrect' ;; esac
```